# CSS animation: fire css animation on class active

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

is it possible to fire up css animation every time class is active?
preview: i have image slider, every time image changes, active class changes too, to current image.

i trying to fire css animation every time that image changed

```css
.article.active {
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: -109px;
  margin-left: -70px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 105;
}

.article-num {
  background: red;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 27px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: movingnum;
  animation-duration: 4.7s;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.article-paragraph {
  top: 24px;
  background: black;
  width: 0;
  height: 23px;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  z-index: 30;
  text-align: right;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: movingpar;
  animation-delay: 400ms;
  animation-duration: 4.2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* keyframes : */
@keyframes movingnum {
  0%,
  100% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  10%,
  90% {
    width: 31px;
    padding: 6.7px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes movingpar {
  0%,
  100% {
    width: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10%,
  90% {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 11px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="swiper-slide" href="views/fourthArticle.html">
  <video id="ctvideo" class="swiper-slide" loop autoplay src="video/staben2miv101217_700.mp4" value="0" muted></video>
  <div class="article active">
    <span class="article-num">04</span>
    <p class="article-paragraph"><strong>text text text</strong></p>
  </div>
</a>
```

In the above example, animation is played just one time. Can I somehow replay animations when some specific requirements are met; like when a parent or sibling elements have `.play` class.

Comment: Which class do you change in your slider?

Comment: `preview: i have image slider, every time image changes, active class changes too, to current image.`-> so check that class which is changing and add animation for that class and check yourself that working or not?

Comment: Gerfried - article class. every image slide i add active class to current article, and removing the previous

Comment: just show your slider this will help

Comment: Yes, add what you are doing in JS here and it would help

Answer (score 0):

**Add Animation to active parents only.**

```css
.article.active {
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: -109px;
  margin-left: -70px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 105;
}

.article-num {
  background: red;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 27px;
  opacity: 0;
 
}
.article.active  .article-num { 
  animation-name: movingnum;
  animation-duration: 4.7s;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;}

.article-paragraph {
  top: 24px;
  background: black;
  width: 0;
  height: 23px;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  z-index: 30;
  text-align: right;
  opacity: 0;

}
.article.active  .article-paragraph{
  animation-name: movingpar;
  animation-delay: 400ms;
  animation-duration: 4.2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

keyframes : @keyframes movingnum {
  0%,
  100% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  10%,
  90% {
    width: 31px;
    padding: 6.7px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes movingpar {
  0%,
  100% {
    width: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10%,
  90% {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 11px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="swiper-slide" href="views/fourthArticle.html">
  <video id="ctvideo" class="swiper-slide" loop autoplay src="video/staben2miv101217_700.mp4" value="0" muted></video>
  <div class="article active">
    <span class="article-num">04</span>
    <p class="article-paragraph"><strong>text text text</strong></p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can use this to run content when the div is active

```html
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="article active">active</div>
  <div class="article">not active</div>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
    if ($('div.article').hasClass('active')) {
    $("div.article").hide();
    $("div.active").show();
    }
 </script>   
</body>
```

Comment: you can add it to your html page using the <script> tags

Comment: yes but the question is, how i fire up this animation when the class is active

Comment: I've edited the answer to hide article when it has active and display only active content.